# What's the name of this shade of blue?

Tags: single-word-requests

[image]

Is it navy blue or another color?

Comment: It's opinion based really. I doubt you'll get complaints from most people for calling it "navy blue" though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Wikipedia's shades of blue page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Shades_of_blue).  Navy is close, but it might be midnight or Oxford blue.  Colors are usually specifically identified for printing, paint, etc. by three digits--the amount of each of red, green and blue, called a Pantone number.

Comment: Also, the appearance in a photograph may vary according to the lighting and equipment settings when the photo was taken.